# Odds ratio interpretation for generalized additive models

Tags: regression, logistic, generalized-additive-model, odds-ratio, mgcv

This is probably a very crude question and I've been thinking about it for a while. Is the odds ratio the same for generalized additive models (GAMs) as it is with generalized linear models (GLMs)? If no, then how can I interpret them in a logistic GAM? I found many links about odds ratios for GAMMs but not GAMs.

Comment: Maybe the slides 60 to 69 from this [excellent workshop](http://r.qcbs.ca/Workshops/workshop08/workshop08-en/workshop08-en.html#60) could bring some light?

Answer (score 0):

First, generalized additive mixed models (GAMMs) are just extensions of generalized additive models (GAMs), so the interpretation of their respective odds ratios is pretty much the same, though of course you are adding in the extra information about random effects. That isn't all that important for your question though.

Remember that odds ratios in generalized linear models (GLMs) are based off single coefficients. Recall that a GAM fit is based off the estimation of *multiple* coefficients using a spline, and this consequently alters how odds ratios (ORs) can be interpreted. As an example, if the data is fit to an almost parabolic association between the predictor and outcome, the odds ratios for each section of this regression would have opposite interpretations.

To show this in action, one can use the `oddsratio` package on a given GAM to check for specific regions of a regression line and it's associated OR. I have used the example given on the [oddsratio package vignette page](https://pat-s.github.io/oddsratio/articles/oddsratio.html) so you can check through the documentation yourself. Below is a GAM fitted from the `data_gam` data in the `oddsratio` package. We use the `or_gam` function by specifying a specific zone of values and it's associated OR:

```
#### Load Libraries ####
library(oddsratio)
library(tidyverse)

#### Fit GAM ####
fit_gam <- mgcv::gam(y ~ s(x0) + s(I(x1^2)) + s(x2) + offset(x3) + x4,
                     data = data_gam
)

#### Check OR for "Cut" ####
or_gam(
  data = data_gam, model = fit_gam, pred = "x2",
  values = c(0.099, 0.198)
)
```

This area of the regression has a considerable OR, as from .099 and .198, there is an associated OR of 23. We can also fit these sections to a plot to visualize what they are saying. You first create a `ggplot` based object with `plot_gam`, then create an OR-based object with `or_gam`, then layer them on top of each other to create a plot with the region of interest.

```
#### Create Plot Object ####
plot_object <- plot_gam(fit_gam, pred = "x2", title = "Predictor 'x2'")

#### Create OR Object ####
or_object <- or_gam(
  data = data_gam, model = fit_gam,
  pred = "x2", values = c(0.099, 0.198)
)

#### Insert OR Object into Plot Object ####
plot <- insert_or(plot_object, or_object,
                  or_yloc = 3,
                  values_xloc = 0.05, arrow_length = 0.02,
                  arrow_col = "red"
)

#### Generate OR Plot ####
plot +
  theme_minimal()
```

[image]

The OR associated with this range makes sense...there is a pretty linear positive trend here. If we fit it to somewhere else with a negative trend:

```
#### Create OR Object ####
or_object <- or_gam(
  data = data_gam, model = fit_gam,
  pred = "x2", values = c(0.3, 0.4)
)

#### Insert OR Object into Plot Object ####
plot <- insert_or(plot_object, or_object,
                  or_yloc = 3,
                  values_xloc = 0.05, arrow_length = 0.02,
                  arrow_col = "red"
)

#### Generate OR Plot ####
plot +
  theme_minimal()
```

We get an almost negligible OR:

[image]

So to summarize, the OR is dependent on where you are looking, but in general it can be interpreted in a similar way.